# Is there a way to stop a segue after prepareForSegue has been called

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, segue

I am developing an app that makes a server call gets an array back and displays it in a table view.
The app has two view controllers (let's called them VC1 and VC2) inside a Navigation controller, so VC1 segues to VC2.
VC1 gets input from the user and validates the input in shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier.
If valid and inside prepareForSegue, VC1 calls a VC2 method using destinationVC that retrieves the array from the server and displays it in a table view.

Now I'm facing the problem that the array returned may be empty and I end up displaying an empty table.

Can I stop the empty table from being displayed or should I make the server call inside shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier in VC1 and stop the segue altogether? I'm confused because the array is the model of VC2 so it seems strange to initiate the server call from VC1 to retrieve data that is part of VC2 model. Is there a way to stop the segue after prepareForSegue has been called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIKit calls the delegate method `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` before calling `prepareForSegue:sender:` Return NO from this method if your array is empty.

Comment: Thanks @ScottAhten, for your answer. But my question is (repharsing it):  to return false from shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender: I have to initiate the server call in VC1 and populate data that belongs to VC2. Am I not violating the MVC pattern by doing that?

Comment: VC1 needs to know if there is data to present. Retrieving the actual data  same time reduces the number of network calls you need to make. The model is retrieved by VC1 and passed to VC2 for display. So, I would say, "No." this isn't a violation of MVC.

Comment: Thanks @ScottAthen. That seems to be the most reasonable way to do it.